# Click event on Font-awesome caret up and caret down stack

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42721254/font-awesome-caret-up-and-caret-down-stacked-on-top-of-each-other) Question. I would like to place `Font-awesome caret up and caret down` like below.

[image]

My HTML code is like below

```
<div class="input-group">
  <div class="qty">
    <input type="text" id="remind_number" placeholder="0">
    <div class="new">
     <div class="" id="plus_remind">
       <i class="fas fa-caret-up"></i>
     </div>
     <div class="" id="minus_remind">
        <i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
```

I am getting a output like below

[image]

My CSS code is like below

```
#plus_remind {
    margin: 0;
    height: 24px;
    width: 22px;
    font: 33px/1 Arial,sans-serif;
    border: 1px solid red;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#minus_remind {   
    height: 24px;
    margin: 0;
    width: 22px;
    font: 33px/1 Arial,sans-serif;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.new {
    margin-top:0 !important;
}
```

My jQuery Code is like below

```
        var bmi = 0
        $("#plus_remind").click(function() {
            bmi = bmi + 1;
            $("#remind_number").val(bmi);
        });

        $("#minus_remind").click(function() {
            bmi = bmi - 1;
            $("#remind_number").val(bmi);
        });
```

Main issue is if I click on `#plus_remind` value is decreasing and if I click on `#minus_remind` value is increasing.

**UPDATE**

Now I am getting output like below

[image]

**Could anyone say how can I place Blue Bordered Caret top of the div just beside Red bordered div ?**

Comment: Please update your question to include what the issue is... Is it a CSS issue as demonstrated in the image, or is it the fact that it's outputting the wrong value?

Comment: Thanks @Studocwho. May be it is CSS issue. Actually one image area is overlapped to another image.

Comment: It works as intended - https://jsfiddle.net/ncgq6mko/

Comment: Thanks @Vandesh. You solution looks like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/KfBXh.png.  I need up and down caret together.

Comment: I thought your question was about the respective clicks not working as intended and not about the positioning

Comment: Thanks @Vandesh. Positioning also related to clicks. My issue is if I click on `#plus_remind` value is decreasing and if I click on `#minus_remind` value is increasing. One image area is overlapped by another image which is created by CSS. That's why I am getting wrong output.

Answer (score 1):

Well I don't understand why you are using font-awesome icons for displaying number if you can do it with single line of statement in html.

Instead of this:

```
<input type="text" id="remind_number" placeholder="0">
```

You can directly use this

```
 <input type="number" id="remind_number" placeholder="0" class="form-control">
```

By using this HTML markup, you won't have to write extra CSS or import any fancy font-awesome code for it. Make sure you have all the bootstrap links in your HTML.

Comment: Thanks @Rohan Rao. Actually it is client's requirement. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There could be a couple of problems based on your overall CSS with related to positioning of the carets, but basically, the overlap causes the intended behaviour to mess up in your case.

A few things to check -

1. All your positioning is correct in terms of `absolute` positioned elements and their heights and widths.
2. Verify if using something like `font: 33px/1 Arial,sans-serif;` doesn't mess up with the size of the elements.

Check and run the snippet below with simple styling to see how it works as intended.

```js
 var bmi = 0
        $("#plus_remind").click(function() {
            bmi = bmi + 1;
            $("#remind_number").val(bmi);
        });

        $("#minus_remind").click(function() {
            bmi = bmi - 1;
            $("#remind_number").val(bmi);
        });
```

```css
.qty{
  position: relative;
  width: 132px;
}
.new{
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  right: 0;
}
#remind_number{
 height: 32px; 
}
#plus_remind, #minus_remind {
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="input-group">
  <div class="qty">
    <input type="text" id="remind_number" placeholder="0">
    <div class="new">
     <div class="" id="plus_remind">
       <i class="fa fa-caret-up"></i>
     </div>
     <div class="" id="minus_remind">
        <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
```